# Problema con linux ubuntu en virtualbox por redimensionar disco virtual

Tags: virtualbox

Tengo windows 7 64bits como sistema y instale virtual box, cree una maquina virtual con lubuntu y redimensione el disco(de 20GB a 30GB) desde virtualbox a traves de DOS, sin embargo al iniciar sesion en linux no me deja ingresar con la contraseña de 
linux, que es de administrador

Comment: te pide contraseña para desbloquear un disco? o es el login al escritorio?

Comment: login de escritorio, al parecer debo volver a montar todo, porque entra y me bota

Comment: ya, preguntaba lo del disco por que hay veces que si tenes tu home encryptado al resizear el disco, el swap (que se encrypta para que no queden datos expuestos) cambia el UUID y hay que resetearlo. entrando por consola tambien te da error? ctrl+alt +f1 debería darte una terminal de texto (alt f7 un par de veces vuelve al interfaz grafico)

Comment: exactamente puedo ingresar a la terminal, estoy viendo la forma de recuperar los datos, gracias

Comment: alo Malbarez, intente hacer lo que dices, no resulto sigue en lo mismo

Answer (score 0):

Lo pude resolver, cambie el uuid con un comando de virtualbox desde windows, que detalla en la siguiente pagina:
https://www.jmramirez.pro/tutorial/resetear-el-uuid-en-virtual-box/
luego cambie el nombre del disco virtual donde se enlaza la maquina virtual y lo volvi a cargar desde virtualbox, eliminando el antiguo y adicionando el nuevo que esta con otro nombre, reinicie la maquina virtual 2 veces y recien
ya me agarra el disco virtual cambiado, gracias: https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/81450/alo-malbarez, por la ayuda